# Can't identify partition in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

After 1.5 years of dual booting Windows 10 and Xubuntu, I just found out about [Linux Subsystem for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide). This is perfect for me, and leaves my Xubuntu installation obsolote. Deleting it ofcourse means that I have to remove some partitions, update my UEFI, remove GRUB, etcetera.

I've looked up some guides and got some help from colleagues, and it all seems like a fairly straightforward thing.

I have a problem however, in the repartitioning part. My hard disk consists of 8 (!) partitions, and there is 1 partition I haven't got the faintest idea of what it's doing of. It's `/dev/nvme0n1p5`, with label `IMAGE`.

I can remember adding at least 2 partitions to my Xubuntu install 1.5 years back, which are the `ext4` and `linux-swap` partitions, but it could also have been 3 partitions, which might explain the `IMAGE` partition.

My computer is a Dell Inspiron, came prepackaged with Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: If NTFS probably a Dell reinstall image or Windows backup of some sort. If you had created your own shared NTFS for data, you may have labeled it data or not labeled at all. When I made my Windows back up with my Dell it asked if I wanted to remove a partition. And same with Dell backup, it asked if I wanted to remove a partition. Back ups on same drive as install are not worth much as when (not if) drive fails it is then difficult to install to new drive unless on external backup drive.

Comment: Hmm, that might be it. I always backup to 2 external drives, but you never know what Dell or Windows did behind the screens. Still keen to hearing other theories though!